# Google Cloud Storage JSON REST API - Get object held in a sub-directory

Tags: get, google-cloud-storage, subdirectory, bucket

I'm looking to access an object I have stored in Google Cloud Storage - this is straightforward enough if the object is stored at the highest level of the bucket using the following call as per the documentation:

https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucketname/o/objectname?alt=media

However, if the file is held within a sub-directory on the bucket I'm unable to access it. There doesn't seem to be any guidance in the docs on this. I've tried the following calls but neither have been successful:

https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucketname/o/foldername/objectname?alt=media
https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucketname/foldername/o/objectname?alt=media

I don't know if the directory is supposed to be submitted as part of the main URL or as a query parameter or somewhere else. Please note that I've submitted the Access Token through the header, too.

I'd also like to be able to store and list objects within a sub-directory so any help with that would be greatly appreciated too.

Could anyone please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to URL encode the `/` in the object name:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints#encoding

therefore it should be (assuming no other `/`):

https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucketname/o/foldername%2Fobjectname?alt=media

Comment: Actually - a couple of follow up questions if I may with regard to how this would work for insert and list calls. For store, this works https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/bucket-name/o?uploadType=media&name=foldername%2objectname, but it then stores the file name on GCS as foldername_filename, which doesn't change functionality but isn't really ideal. 2) For listing objects in a bucket, not sure where the syntax for a nested directory should go in here: https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucketname/o. Any info much appreciated...

Comment: I saw in your comment that you had a typo, instead of using `%2F` you're using `%2`, if you combine the `%2` with a letter on your object name it's probable that you ended up with a different substitution, whole URL:

`https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/bucket/o?name=folder%2objectname`